# Automatically use usb0 network if available

Tags: networking, tethering

How can I automatically use my usb0 network if it's available (in favour of using eth0) for any internet connectivity.

Currently, I plug in my phone to tether and then I have to run:

`sudo ip route change to default dev usb0 via 192.168.42.129`

It would be great if I could set up a "favour" or priority some how? Because, frequently I forget to run this (or it becomes tiresome running each time). Occassionally, the USB will drop out also and I have to notice that it's switched back to eth0 as the default.
Any thoughts to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you want to use eth0 at all when the tether is active?

Comment: Yes. I need to use eth0 in order to use synergy and to connect to my AVR. I don't want to use it for anything outside of the network though. (Otherwise, yes, the obvious solution would be to just pull out eth0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Make script in the folder /etc/network/if-up.d/ called script with execute permissions 755

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" != "usb0" ] || exit 0
# Adding additional routes on connection
route add default dev usb0 via 192.168.42.129
route add ...
route add ...
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This seems to be exactly what I'd want.